# manage booting OS remotely in dual boot windows-linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot, remote

I have a cluster of systems(somewhat like Beowulf configuration). I have to install windows(XP x64 is preferable) and Linux(Debian or Ubuntu) as dual-boot system on each of 30 computer. Now I want to remotely boot or reboot systems into a specific OS. I know I can change grub configuration of each node to set default OS in next boot; but I prefer a more automated way than remotely edit grub configuration of each computer and then restart them.

Is there a way or a program that can manage boot process remotely(something just like WakeOnLan system) and support both windows and linux and replace grub? or any other automated method!

Answer (score 2):

Boot them all via PXE.  On you PXE server configure a bootloader that loads the preferred OS.

- pxelinux bootloader: http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/PXELINUX

  - Note the config file is loaded, this can be used to link systems to different config files.
- Chainload http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Comboot/chain.c32

Comment: thanks but can you help me find an instruction to do that? can I boot some nodes in windows and some linux with a PXE server?

Comment: Well the idea is that you just chainload to an an OS installed on the machine.  I have added a couple links to specific details for pxelinux.  If you use a different pxe bootloader you are one your own.