# How to change boot_drive/operating_system from within that operating system?

Tags: linux, windows-10, remote-desktop, multi-boot, grub

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to change boot drive or operating system that PC will boot into during the next startup but from within that operating system (!) as oppose to just going into BIOS's boot menu and changing startup diskю

My setup is a bit cumbersome but please bear with me.
I have a PC with two drives:

1. Windows 10
2. Linux Mint

The behaviour I'm trying to achieve is to be able to boot (let's say) into Windows 10. And from within Window 10 **[do something]** that will make my PC boot into Linux after restart (as oppose to just booting back into Windows) and vice versa (meaning that when I boot into Linx Mint I want to be able to **[do something]** that will make my PC boot into Windows 10 during the next startup)

The reason why I can't just boot into BIOS's boot menu is that this PC I'm talking about is a headless server that I "remotely log-into" from another PC via LAN (Sunshine/Moonlight)

Now here's my current line of thinking:
Windows's 'bootloader' can't boot into Linux, but Linux's bootloader (grub) can boot into Windows. So I can (while being inside Linux) - I can edit /etc/default/grub file and modify GRUB_DEFAULT="Win10" entry (and update-grub of course) so that it would boot into Windows during the next startup. So 50% of the solution is already working. But! How do I (while working within Windows 10) tell my PC that I would like to boot into Linux during the next startup?

Windows can't read (without excessive and potencially dangerous shenanigans) Linux's ext4 filesystem and even if I could and somehow managed to modify grub file, how do I rebuild it from within Windows?

Do you see what I'm trying to achieve? Does anyone have any idea? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

There’s a [grubchoosedefault](https://de.mcbf.net/david/grubchoosedefault/) tool that promises such functionality but it assumes that I have my grub on an ext2/3 filesystem (which is not the case) and that I'm willing to use 3rd party tools in order to access Linux's filesystem (which I'm not. I had an experience using suhc tool in the past, it messed up the entire drive and it's indexing)

Comment: It should be trivial to configure GRUB to present a boot menu., allowing you to select which operating system you want. While not exactly what you want, what you actually want, isn’t possible

Comment: @Ramhound I appriciate that you took the time to read and reply but I've learned to use the word 'impossible' with great causion. As I mentioned in my update there is a [grubchoosedefault](https://de.mcbf.net/david/grubchoosedefault/) tool which (seemingly) does what I described but only if filesystem is ext2/3 (I use ext4) and I'm willing to use 3rd party tools in order to access Linux's filesystem (I'm not)

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/a/1785545/1686 answer the question?

Comment: @u1686_grawity thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `grub-reboot` command.

```
Set the default boot menu entry for GRUB, for the next boot only.
```

It does require some jumping through a few hoops to get it setup right, but then, when you invoke this, it tells grub where the next boot should go.  So in Linux you invoke this, and then reboot, and you get to Windows or whatever other OS you  want.   And when another OS reboots, grub is back to it's standard configuration and boots Linux normally.

The other option would be to find one of the Linux builds designed to boot another OS, Linux or Windows etc... and make it your normal boot.  Then you network to it and tell it which other OS to boot.  While I've seen one of these, I can't tell you the name at this point.

P.S. Personally, I just wish GRUB had a VNC console mode.  :-)