Bootloader with RDP support?
Situation: I got 2 operating systems that I actively use (Windows and Linux).
The problem: I am unable to switch between each other remotely.
Is there any solution to be able to remotely boot to another system? Virtual machine is not an option in my case. I tried to find it in other places, but there seem to be no actual solution than a hardware one.
For me optimal option would be some bootloader with RDP support or some app that would reboot the system to other one. First one preferred.

Have you already tried, and ruled out, previous answers such as https://superuser.com/a/1785545?

this is not what I am looking for... waay too complicated when you have to do it often, and I am looking for a solution for people that are not into IT at all

If you don't want a complicated solution then you may have to pay money and get an Ethernet KVM.

Ok I have mentioned in the question that I wouldn't like to use hardware solution, but if there is no other way... pretty weird to be honest, that there isn't.

See if this answer solves your problem.

This kind of solves a problem, but still like the previous answer... there is no easy multisystem GUI software for that does that? Maybe I will have to write one myself. Still... that there is no bootleader with RDP support is kinda weird? What's the problem to make one? That it doesn't have access to other devices before booting? So make it after the first boot and tunnel the booting to other one? Not sure, if it would work, as I am not familiar in hardware limitations in the subject, but that would be a desired solution for many people.


like the previous comment


@FlashThunder it's not that weird, it's just not really a normal use case for home systems and adds a lot of complexity (networking and video capture/encoding) to a system whose entire job is to be as small as possible while booting a computer. Just the video capture requires either an emulated display or ability to directly read graphics memory which could be in any number of formats depending on how it gets set up and reconfigured during the boot process. It's not as simple as just "send display over network". Computers that require remote management (servers) tend to have special hardware.

RDP's mostly MS only - the 'simple' answer is though, you'd need a full network stack and more to do RDP or VNC, and that's more than you'd usually need for a bootloader. While modern UEFI is fairly OS like on its own, you're essentially requiring a  good chunk of a small OS to get this capbility, and dualboot is relatively niche.

Another option is by using a server that has this build in. For example HP Servers have ilo which has its own dedicated network port that talks directly to the bios. You can remote in, and from there see whatever is on the screen, and thus also switch OSses or change BIOS settings.

@FlashThunder - to clarify, running a couple of commands is "too complicated", but writing a multi-platform GUI tool (presumably to wrap those commands or an equivelant) is not? This is trivially scriptable, if you just want to run something to make it happen.

@Attie yes... it's not only for me

If you're content with Windows being your default boot target, and then rebooting into Linux, you could use this little utility: bootnext (disclaimer: I've not tried it, and it's not been updated for ~4 years... there may be other options). Rebooting once in Linux will land you back in Windows each time.

If you want (need?) to use RDP and a GUI to deal with this at boot time, then perhaps your best approach is to produce a small Linux system, which you configure as your default boot target. I don't know if something like this exists, but from your comment, it sounds like you're up for it.
Inside this small Linux environment, you set up an RDP server and implement a graphical utility. The graphical utility then does something between executing the following commands directly and scraping the output, or interfacing with /sys/firmware/efi/efivars directly. You can even implement your own timeout and default mechanisms.
This answer (mentioned in the comments) has some good additional information on the topic.
Enumerate Boot Options
Running efibootmgr will present a list of boot options, example below. This needs to be parsed and converted into elements in your UI.
BootCurrent: 0001
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* Ubuntu
Boot001F  USB HDD

Configure Next Boot Option
Allow the user to select an option presented above, and then run efibootmgr --bootnext ${option}. This will configure the boot mode given in ${option} for one boot only - the system will then revert to this small Linux environment on the subsequent boot.
Reboot
When the user clicks "Go!", reboot the system (e.g: reboot) - whichever boot mode was selected above will be started, and the system can be used.
On the next boot (or reboot), the small Linux environment will be run again, allowing the user to connect via RDP and select a new boot mode.
